# How to always keep spikes in Plotlly.js or trigger them programatically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, plotly

[image: Spikes showed on hover.]

Spikes are only shown when you hover over a point in plotly. I'm currently trying to programmatically trigger the drawing of spikes in scatter 3d plots in Plotlly. I've been reading the source code and I can't seem to figure out how to always draw spikes or programmatically trigger them.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: With "spikes" do you mean the hoverinfo/labels?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So when you over a point, it shows the hover label for that point but also a spikes which are lines extruding from the point and touching the x/y, z/x, y/z planes. They are called spikes in the scatter3d documentation.